# Identifying data with different occurrences

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

How to find the animals with different test dates?

[image: Table name - animals]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find animals which have 2 or more distinct dates then you can use `COUNT` along with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT animals_key, anim_ident
FROM jt3
GROUP BY animals_key, anim_ident
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT test_date) > 1
```

If you want to also include test date information, then you can join the above query to the original table.